# "Closet" vs. "Wardrobe" Why is the first more common in the US?

Tags: word-usage, american-english, british-english, transatlantic-differences

I believe that speakers on both sides of the pond (i.e. the Atlantic Ocean) are familiar with the terms *closet* and *wardrobe*. The first is distinctly American, and the latter is used in the UK. Oxford Dictionaries offer the following tidbits

> **[closet](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/closet)**
>   North American
>   **1.** A tall cupboard or wardrobe with a door, used for storage.
>   ‘*he has a closet full of designer suits*’
>
> **Origin**
>   Late Middle English (denoting a private or small room): from Old French, diminutive of *clos* ‘closed’

and

> **[wardrobe](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/wardrobe)**
>   **1.** A large, tall cupboard or recess in which clothes may be hung or stored.
>   ‘*All of the bedrooms have fitted wardrobes and wash hand basins while one rear bedroom also has an en-suite shower room.*’
>
> **Origin**
>   Middle English (in the sense ‘private chamber’): from Old Northern French *warderobe*, variant of Old French *garderobe*

I do not live in the US nor in the UK but I would like to know whether Americans ever use the word "wardrobe", in the sense of furniture,  instead of *closet*.

Similarly, if both terms are derived from Middle English, and both are French loanwords why did "closet" catch on in the States but not in the UK? For example, was the term "closet" more commonly used in England at the time when the Pilgrims left Plymouth and boarded the Mayflower in 1620? Has the meaning or its usage changed in the last fifty years, etc.?

**Clarification note**

I am not interested so much in the different meanings and idiomatic usages of *closet* and *wardrobe*, but as to why one term for a piece of bedroom furniture was preferred to the other.

Comment: If you're not interested in the different meanings, how will you know which word to use? In my (eastern US, NY to FL) experience, wardrobe is usually meant for free-standing furniture and closet for a built-in room. Don't just rely on dictionary definitions - **do image searches**. ;)

Comment: @Davo the room where one hangs their suits and clothes is called a [walk-in wardrobe](https://www.google.com/search?q=walk+in+wardrobe&oq=walk+in+wardrobe&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) in the UK. I am specifically speaking about the piece of furniture in this question.

Comment: Answers to 'why' questions are difficult. Are you looking for a linguistic or cultural answer? Maybe house builders in the US more often build built-in wardrobes/closets than the UK (and this would fit US usage at least where the built-in is called a closet and the stand-alone is called a wardrobe (and stand-alones are rare in the US).

Comment: Is there a reason why you're asking about the Pilgrims? The permanent settlement at [Jamestown, Virginia](https://www.nps.gov/jame/learn/historyculture/a-short-history-of-jamestown.htm) predated any landing & settlement by the Pilgrims.

Comment: The question suffers from asking *why*. See [meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11026/what-about-my-question-deserves-a-negative-score). Also  who says 'closet' is more popular in the US than 'wardrobe'? In the US they refer to two different things. When they are used to refer to the correct object, one is not more popular than the other.

Comment: Welcone back Clare, we missed your cheerful contributions. As I already stated I don't live in the US or in the UK any longer, however, I do know that "closet" is typically N.American. I never said that  wardrobe is not used in the US but I can certainly ask "why" closet is more common in the US than in the UK.

Comment: Are you saying that English speakers in the UK call small rooms for storage *wardrobes* instead of *closets*? Or perhaps closets just aren't very common in the UK? Otherwise, I don't understand the question. No American would ever call a piece of furniture a *closet*. Closets and wardrobes are two *entirely* different things.

Comment: I think you should make clear what you are looking for. The fact that none of the answer fits, is a clear signal that the question is unclear. My assumption that you are asking  why closet in more common in the USA rather than in the UK is obviously off target.

Comment: Still wondering what the departure of the Pilgrims from Plymouth has to do with anything. Are you asking whether the use of one word or another by the Pilgrims was influenced by their ~12-year stay in the Netherlands?

Comment: @Clare I bow to your superior knowledge and expertise. I am an ignoramus where the history of the United States is concerned. My idea, was just that, an idea, it was not meant to be an answer. The English language, I think, began to diverge and really evolve when many English settlers had emigrated to the US,  so I opted for one of the most famous voyages undertaken by the Pilgrims or the Puritans. The settlers took with them "closet" while those who remained began to use "wardrobe" more and more often. Again, apologies if my question or reasoning is unclear.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70295/discussion-on-question-by-mari-lou-a-closet-vs-wardrobe-why-is-the-first-mo).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**TL;DR: The term "closet" shows up much more in American writing and speech because closets (the architectural feature) are much more common than wardrobes (the piece of furniture) in American homes, and have been for a century or more.**

I agree with GEdgar's answer that in the US, a *closet* is an architectural feature—essentially a small room (possibly very small)—whereas a *wardrobe* is a piece of furniture (or possibly the collection of clothes that can be held in either).<sup>1</sup> In my experience, the terms are not generally used interchangeably for either the built-in home feature or the casegood, though I can imagine that in a pinch someone who couldn't bring to mind the appropriate word for a piece of furniture might call it a "closet thing" or similar.

Both terms are also in extended use: For example, a large packing box fitted with a bar for hanging clothes is typically called a [*wardrobe box*](https://www.uhaul.com/MovingSupplies/Boxes/Clothing-Moving-Boxes/Grand-Wardrobe-Box?Id=6560) (see, e.g., U-Haul); there are many different types of closet ([*linen closets*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/linen%20closet)<sup>2</sup>, [*supply closets*](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/supply+closet)<sup>3</sup>, [*coat closets*](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/coat+closet)<sup>4</sup>, etc.); and when something doesn't quite fit either category advertisers may employ both terms at once, as in the [*Honey-Can-Do® 68-Inch Steel Freestanding **Wardrobe Closet***](https://www.bedbathandbeyond.com/store/product/honey-can-do-reg-68-inch-steel-freestanding-wardrobe-closet/1041243794?skuId=41243794&mcid=PS_googlepla_nonbrand_storage_online&product_id=41243794&adtype=pla&product_channel=online&adpos=1o6&creative=224122691883&device=c&matchtype=&network=g&mrkgadid=3140840096&mrkgcl=609&rkg_id=h-a3fe600cbb2a427c350ba66ea58b60c6_t-1513787299&gclid=CjwKCAiAsejRBRB3EiwAZft7sJE-1Q-_AQKyxU_LndUw6PV9hB3dS2Jd-pJENhLYfagShGNUjUehhxoC82EQAvD_BwE) (from retailer Bed Bath & Beyond), a wire shelving unit whose blurb reads:

> Update the inside of your closet or create extra storage space with the Honey-Can-Do freestanding wardrobe closet. This portable system keeps clothes, shoes and other items organized.

Thus the word *closet* is not really preferred over *wardrobe* in the US in the sense of having replaced it as the "correct" term—both terms are still in common use by most adult AmE speakers, just for two different concepts. However, the word "closet" is, indeed, far more common in American speech and writing. For example, a Google Ngram comparing "closet" and "wardrobe" (case insensitive; [typical Ngram caveats](https://www.wired.com/2015/10/pitfalls-of-studying-language-with-google-ngram/) apply) shows that as of 2000, the term "closet" was almost three times as common as "wardrobe" in Ngram's American English corpus. In fact, "closet" has been more common than "wardrobe" in American English writing for over two centuries. The usage of "wardrobe" held fairly steady from 1800–2000, whereas "closet" gradually declined to the mid-1960s and then began a fairly steep rise.

[image: ![Google Ngram showing case-insensitive comparison of terms "closet" and "wardrobe" from 1800 to 2000 in American English. "Closet" is consistently more common than "wardrobe"; the "closet" curves shows a very jagged, very slight decline from around 0.00075% in the early 1800s to a low of just below 0.0004% in the mid-1960s, before beginning a steep and steady rise to a high of about 0.00085% in 2000. "Wardrobe" begins at just under 0.0002% in 1880, climbs up to a high of just over 0.0003% in the mid-1850s, then hovers drifts up and down between 0.0002% and 0.0003% for the rest of the chart.]

The reason for this disparity has to do with architectural history: in the US, built-in clothing storage, AKA closets, are virtually ubiquitous, and have been for a very long time. This means that there is less need for furniture in which to hang clothes. So we talk about closets more than about wardrobes, because we have more closets than we do wardrobes.

The [*New York Times* reports in their timeline "A Few Niches in Closet History"](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2013/04/07/realestate/20130407-closets-timeline.html) that an early-adopter of closets in that city was a luxury apartment building constructed in 1880. A real estate expert quoted in [the associated article](http://www.nytimes.com/2013/04/07/realestate/closets-please-and-the-bigger-the-better.html)<sup>5</sup> notes that today,

> In general, regular closets are 3 by 5 feet, while walk-in closets are 5 by 8 feet . . . .

But the timeline also highlights a couple of "closets" that look more like entire rooms or even boutiques, the new aspirational closet (full disclosure: I converted a small second kitchen in my 1900 farmhouse into a "sleep-in" closet, complete with its own closet, though the contents are nothing like as luxe as Carey's/Carrie's).

In parts of the US where space is at less of a premium, closets have been common for even longer. A couple of articles on the history of Iowa home architecture<sup>6</sup> show small closets in homes built as early as the mid-1800s, and common for houses built by the end of that century. And modern homes in the US are [expected to have a closet in every bedroom](https://www.trulia.com/voices/Home_Selling/Does_a_room_need_a_built_in_closet_before_it_can_b-486263) (even if that's [not usually a legal requirement](https://www.realtor.com/advice/sell/what-is-a-bedroom-features/)).

In this architectural context, wardrobes (the clothing storage furniture item) are used largely by folks with what most Americans would consider sub-standard closet space. [One article, which recommends various wardrobe options](https://www.apartmenttherapy.com/storing-clothes-in-apartments-with-no-closets-213679)<sup>7</sup>, opens:

> So you've found the perfect apartment, with great light, in a great neighborhood, only — it doesn't have any closets. You could throw away all of your clothes, or, if wearing the same outfit for the rest of your life sounds like too much of a sacrifice, you could check out some of these ideas . . . .

Note the dramatic pause (punctuationally speaking) introducing the desperate lack of closets.

In fact, there is so little call for separate furniture for hanging clothing that there is a small cottage industry dedicated to repurposing such furniture. As DIY columnist Elise Moreau puts it in her [*Decoist* article "15 Creative Ways to Repurpose an Old Antique Armoire"](https://www.decoist.com/repurpose-antique-armoire/),

> An antique armoire can bring a sense of timeless elegance to any home, but not everyone can find a proper use for one — not to mention sufficient space too! In the old days they were used to store clothing and linens back when bedrooms didn’t have closets, and today some people use them to hold their televisions — but that trend perhaps isn’t as big of a deal as it once was now that TV screens are so flat and compact. In any case, if you do have the room for it, i[t] certainly isn’t impossible to find some kind of use for an armoire.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>The piece of furniture is also sometimes called an [armoire](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/armoire), and if it is combined with a chest of drawers it may be called a [chiffarobe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chifforobe). I'm sure there are other terms in regional use, too—possibly even *closet*. I note that even [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/closet) lists "a **cabinet** or recess" as a possible meaning of closet, so it's likely that someone in the US says this or did at one time, but it is far from common now.</sub>
<sup>2</sup> <sub>(M-W; traditionally literally for towels and bed linens, but now likely to also house other bed & bath necessities)</sub>
<sup>3</sup> <sub>The Free Dictionary; just what it sounds like, but usually found at places of business rather than in homes</sub>
<sup>4</sup> <sub>TFD; found generally near the entrance(s) of a home</sub>
<sup>5</sup> <sub>"Closets, Please, and the Bigger the Better", by Elissa Gootman, April 5, 2013</sub>
<sup>6</sup>  See ["A Historical Look at Architecture in Iowa." *The Annals of Iowa* 38 (1967), 481-500](http://ir.uiowa.edu/annals-of-iowa/vol38/iss7/2) and [Peterson, Fred W. "Tradition and Change in Nineteenth-Century Iowa Farmhouses." *The Annals of
Iowa* 52 (1993), 251-281](http://ir.uiowa.edu/annals-of-iowa/vol52/iss3/3)
<sup>7</sup>  Nancy Mitchell, “Ideas & Inspiration: Storing Clothes in Apartments with No Closets”, Apartment Therapy, Dec. 29, 2015

Comment: Excellent answer and I upvote! One of my friends even wondered if the famous novel should have been retitled thus when published in the USA: http://cherwell.org/2011/02/07/the-lion-the-witch-and-thecloset/

Answer (score 87):

I agree with Hot Licks.  I am in the US.  A **wardrobe** is a movable piece of furniture

[image: wardrobe]

but a **closet** is built in to the house.

[image: closet]
A closet may have doors, unlike this one.

As a child, when I read *The Lion, the Witch, and the Wardrobe*, I imagined something like the first picture.  I wonder if kids in England imagine something like the second picture?

Comment: No; UK usage of "wardrobe" appears to be the same as US. I'd guess that one reason that the word "closet" (in this context) isn't as common in the UK is that homes here tend not to have closets, possibly because UK homes are, on average, smaller than in the US.

Comment: Another distinction is that a 'closet' in the US isn't always designed or used to hold clothes e.g. a "utility closet".

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff: In the UK when a home does have what in the US would be called a closet, it's more usually referred to as a "walk-in wardrobe", or possibly "fitted wardrobe" (although that would more often be more like a cupboard built into the room).

Comment: I (BrE) would call picture 2 a built-in wardrobe, and, yes, C.S.Lewis's wardrobe would have been like picture 1. See http://www.paulinebaynes.com/?what=artifacts&image_id=575

Comment: @KateBunting: Good call, #2 is eliminated by the text of _The Magician's Nephew_.

Comment: @psmear I think a walk in wardrobe would be a roomlike fitted wardrobe (think rails heading away from the door so you can literally walk into it)

Comment: @RichardTingle: Yes - and that's been my experience of what people in the US mean when they refer to a "closet"... though I expect, as with many things, there is a lot of variation!

Comment: @psmears We use the term "walk-in closets" in the US for closets that are substantially deeper and usually larger than the image shown (sometimes much larger—essentially an entire room). Walk-ins are much-prized in US real estate, but very large closets aren't really the norm, except in very affluent areas.

Comment: @JimmyJames see also: water closet   ;-)

Comment: @1006a would you call the 2nd image a closet, even if there are no doors? In Britain I'm not even convinced that would be called a *built-in wardrobe* in the UK, it's almost a niche.

Comment: @Mari-LouA While I would be slightly confused as to *why* it doesn't have doors, I wouldn't really think of calling it anything other than a closet. If it were empty there would be some ambiguity, but having a distinct frame would probably still make it more of a closet rather than a "nook" or "niche".

Comment: @1006a Walk in closets are more common in newer construction.  In affluent areas with older homes, the closets would typically not be walk-in unless there was a renovation.  A lot of middle class tract housing would have a walk-in closet in the master bedroom.  A trend that I've seen is that  they often have a washer and dryer in that walk-in closet.

Comment: Another US speaker here.  Agree 100% with Rob K, GEdgar, and Kamil.  "Closet" does not refer to a piece of furniture.  I would definitely choose "closet" over "nook" or "niche" for picture 2.  Both the contents and the molding probably contribute to this.  Where I am (New England), I rarely hear the piece of furniture referred to as a 'wardrobe".  I usually hear it referred to as an "armoire".

Comment: @1006a hi, I was wondering if you could just copy and paste your comments into an answer. I really appreciated your brief and apposite explanations and they have been upvoted several times. I'm thinking of answering my own question but before doing so, I wanted to ask you one last time.

Comment: Sorry! I've actually been working on an answer, but the end of the term/approaching holidays and two sick kids (not to mention the healthy ones) have kept me offline for most of the past several days. I'll post what I've got this morning.

Comment: @Joshua - I think #2 is eliminated in a *water closet*.

Comment: @JimmyJames Here in Canada we'd be more likely to call the "utility closet" a *cupboard*.

Comment: While any native AmE speaker would *understand* this common differentiation of "wardrobe" and "closet", be advised that in New England,  the term "cupboard" is most commonly used for both. (Although you might not recognize it - as it is pronounced "cubbit".)

Answer (score 7):

It appears [closet](http://www.worldwidewords.org/articles/ar-clo1.htm)  fell out of favour in the UK in the 19th century probably because of the rise of the expression water closet, but not in the USA. As shown in [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=closet%3Aeng_us_2012%2Ccloset%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Cwardrobe%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cwardrobe%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccloset%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccloset%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwardrobe%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwardrobe%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0http://) closet is much more common in the USA, while wardrobe is common in BrE and AmE.

> - A couple of centuries ago, closet was common in British English in two senses, that of a small private room or inner chamber for retirement or study and for a small room, leading off a larger one, ***hence any small storage space. This fits the etymology, as closet is from the Old French closet, a diminutive of Latin clos, closed.*** In its early days, a cupboard was literally a board on which to store or display cups and other vessels, then a piece of furniture, one that we British would now call a sideboard, and also a storage space, usually one with shelves.
> - Closet slowly fell out of use during the nineteenth century, perhaps because the rise of water closet (WC), using closet in its sense of a small private room, made it a less suitable word for polite conversation in Victorian times. ***For whatever reason, the shift didn't take place in the US, where closet has always been dominant, with cupboard a lesser used variant***.

(WorldWideWords)